# How to implement a role based user management system with ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, roles

Although I'm new to ASP.NET I have to implement a role based user management system for an ASP.NET MVC 4 application (Visual Studio 2010). Users have one or more of these roles: Admin, Manager, User. Based on the role users have access to different areas. There is a predefined table with users.

I know that ASP.NET provides something to implement this requirement but I am confused by the information I get. Even though there is a lot of information I can't find an adequate documentation or blog post. Everything starts and ends somewhere else. There seem to be many different but similar solutions.

Sorry for asking such a broad question but I have the impression that I am not the only one confused by this. A pointer to a good documentation or an example project would help me a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at this:

[SimpleMembership, Membership Providers, Universal Providers and the new ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC 4 templates](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx)

It a new feature that simplify all the membership/role management.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an article for ASP.NET MVC 3 (Razor) that covers membership and roles. I don't believe things changed greatly between MVC 3 and 4 with regard to the builit-in membership provider - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/b19d5a/membership-and-authorization-in-Asp-Net-mvc-3-razor/

Additionally, here is the portion of Microsoft's Music Store tutorial that deals with membership - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7

Hope they help.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to use a web application framework. See http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/

Also, See http://www.aspnetzero.com/ it has ready user, role.. management pages and can be good start point for new applications.