# Roles and Security in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, roles

Can anyone tell me the best way to implement Roles and security in ASP.NET MVC4 app.

I am working on a MVC project and I want to implement the roles and security in that project. I have roles defined which I am getting from the database.But I dont know how to use those roles in my project. How can I make a connection(in webconfig or something) from which I can declare the roles on the Action method so that only users with those roles can only access that method.

Like I have some roles : **Read,Edit,Update**..I want only users with read role to only perform read operation and other operations respectively depending on roles.

I know this is a very broad question.but I just want to know the best way using which I can implement the roles and security in my application.

What will be the step by step process:

Do I need to make some connection in the webconfig so that the dataannotation with the role defined work or something..

Plz help me guys. Thanks.

Comment: Try these links http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I am not using forms..I have a Asp.net mvc4 web application

Comment: The link details out authentication in MVC 4 app. Also below there is a  link for role management as well.

Comment: Also check this  link out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971081/how-to-implement-a-role-based-user-management-system-with-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: There is an attribute which you can use on every method. it looks like this - '[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
}'

Answer (score 0):

Which authentication mode are you using? Forms authentication has option User.IsInRole but for that to work, you need to have `Forms Authentication` in place. [User.IsInRole MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.user.isinrole%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

What you can do is `create different views for Details, Insert/Update, Delete.` Then, on each controller, you just allow the users with your desired roles.

Comment: can you tell me the best way to implement roles and security in MVC4. i have created a custom "AuthorizeAttribute" which I am using on my action method

Comment: `User.IsInRole()` will also work with other authentication mechanisms depending on the environment.

Comment: I have defined DataAnnotation on the controllers method.I just want to  know the best way to implement these defined roles

Comment: @Farzi you have to issue a forms authentication ticket & store your roles in that ticket. Then you fetch the roles through User.IsInRole("YourRole"). That is why I asked what type of authentication mode you are using? I have used this with Forms authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you actually needed is RBAC.

User has one or more roles, and there are many functions for each role.

User & Role, One to Many or Many to Many
Role & Function, Many to Many

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control

Add an AuthorizeAttribute(eg: MyAuthorize) class.

```
[MyAuthorize("Admin-User-Add")]
public ActionResult Add(){}
```

"Admin-User-Add" is the unique key of the function of "Add user action".